# Routing difficulties (Non-MVC) in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I'm having a problem with my routing behavior. And I can't figure out if the problem is with my programming or is a hosting problem.

I register this route on the Application_Start method in the global.asax.cs

```
routes.MapPageRoute("redir", "{pagename}", "~/routehandler.aspx");
```

Its the simplest route there is, and should allow me to route simple requests like

```
www.mypage.com/pagename
```

The thing is, that while this works perfectly in my development environment, when I upload it to my host, it kinds of breaks down whenever it wants to. 
It will work great for some time, and then, for a number of hours everyday, it just wont work. I've tried restarting the website, writing a bunch of code forcing the routes to register on every single request, everything. Yet, for a bunch of time everyday, using this route just shows me a 404 page.

I don't have URL Rewrite module available.

So, my question is, is my hosting service screwing me or am I just writing the wrong code?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked in your server event log to see what is happening around the time it breaks down?

Comment: do you have access to http logs? does your host use more than one server to handle your site? does your host use a load balancer or other form of application firewall/gateway that is configured between you and your site?

Comment: Have you confirmed that it's .NET that's handling the 404? If it's a hosting environment that supports PHP and .NET it's possible that there is another module on the server that is processing the request before your module.

Comment: Ok, to clarify, I don't have access to the server event log, its just one of those cheap .net hostings (12 bucks a month). So everything comes pre-packaged with this crappy html interface :S.
And there was an option for PHP in it, I turned it down, and immediately stopped working when it worked like 5 minutes ago.
I think i fixed it with the worst piece of code I've written, checking every request, filtering pages, images, css, js, etc and redirecting by force.